# Why do we need a separate config file "sbtconfig.txt" only for Windows?

Tags: scala, sbt

There are two config files in sbt 1.3.0, one is sbtconfig.txt, and the other is sbtopts. Say we want to set a Java System Property which is "-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true".  When I use Windows, it should set in sbtconfig.txt file, and if I use Mac/Linux, it should be set in sbtopts file. So why don't we unify these two config files for all operating systems?